# DLL are loaded at the same address, why is it designed like that?

Tags: windows, dll, aslr

In Windows the same DLL are loaded in the same address across processes, e.g advapi32.dll

WmiPrvSE.exe:

[image]

svchost.exe:

[image]

Since windows has ASLR enabled, why is it designed like that?

Comment: Every DLL indicates its preferred load address (/BASE linker option).  Programmers don't often do that for their own DLLs, but Microsoft does.  That address then gets randomized by ASLR, consistent across processes for the current boot session.  With the advantage that the DLL only needs to be loaded into memory once, usable by any process.  Quicker process start times, less RAM, less commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASLR randomizes the load address offset when the machine boots, it is not random per-process. ASLR protects you from code injected by a webpage etc. not from processes already running on your machine.

Loading at the same address in every process is advantageous for page sharing but not guaranteed by the OS. Low-level libraries are more likely to load at the same address and advapi32 is pretty low-level.

Comment: I created a hello-world DLL (which is not a low-level one). Then I use CreateRemoteThread to inject it to multiple processes and it's also loaded in the same base address, very interesting.

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't collide with a already loaded dll it will load in the same place. Ntdll and kernel32 always will, the rest depends on which DLLs are loaded and when.